# Where to use "alive with pleasure"

Tags: expressions

In one of Friends episode, after Ross changes Chandler's nicotine patch, Chandler says sarcastic:
[image]

> Ooh, I'm alive with pleasure now.

I can guess it's meaning, but I need to know where we use it typically.
Thanks

Comment: Does the picture serve any purpose?

Comment: We don't typically use it.  Chandler's line is a reference to [an old series of Newport cigarette ads](http://flashbak.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Newport-cigarettes-with-trombone.jpg), which showed people having fun (which was somehow supposed to be connected with smoking Newport cigarettes) that used the line "Alive with pleasure!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's quoting a tagline from a famous set of magazine ads that were quite common in the 1980s:

[image]
[image]

To the best of my knowledge, the saying isn't used all that often outside of that ad campaign.

Comment: +1 Well remembered, this would be the allusion being made since both are smoking related.

Comment: Which is to say, you shouldn't use it unless you are referring to the cigarette ad, and talking to people who remember the cigarette ad.  Which is to say, older people  :)

Comment: @Andrew - Or to younger people watching older reruns....

Comment: @J.R. Are reruns now broadcast with the original ads?

Comment: @StoneyB Now that is a great idea for a niche channel for all those "period" people. It is very jarring watching Lawrence Welk and having an ad for Best Buy come on.

Answer (score 0):

You may also find this helpful:

Alive with pleasure is a state of euphoria experienced by a shrinking number of select people who enjoy everything that life has to offer, and aren't afraid of asking for more. Not content with the joy of living alone, these people have no problem taking risks and living a life that others fear to imagine. No cares, no worries.

People who are alive with pleasure are the jet set, the happening crowd, and people in the know.

Are you missing out on this type of lifestyle? Do you ever wonder what it would be like to take advantage of the miracles of modern science in helping to prolong you life?

The answer to your curiosity, your thirst for everything that life has to offer can be answered in four simple world that will help you understand the true meaning of “alive with pleasure”:
Start Smoking Cigarettes Today!

http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Alive_with_pleasure

Comment: Uncyclopedia is a spoof and not a useful source for serious advice.

Comment: @David Richerby: Fair enough! Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Where to use "alive with pleasure"?

Honestly, nowhere. Unless you're obviously being sarcastic or obviously referencing the series of ads (which most people who weren't in the USA in the 1980s will fail to recognize), any time you use a phrase like that is going to sound like a badly written sex scene in a trashy romance novel.